# An Alternative to Counter Columns in ScyllaDB

Tags: cassandra, nosql, counter, scylla

According to [the official documentation](https://docs.scylladb.com/using-scylla/counters/), among the restrictions on counter columns in `ScyllaDB` are:

```
The only other columns in a table with a counter column can be columns of the primary key (which cannot be updated). No other kinds of column can be included. This limitation safeguards correct handling of counter and non-counter updates by not allowing them in the same operation.

All non-counters columns in the table must be part of the primary key.

Counter columns, on the other hand, may not be part of the primary key.
```

In my table design I have hundreds of rows where each row needs to be linked to a counter column.

The table has the following structure:

```
K1 K2 C1 C2 C3 V1 V2 V3 COUNTER
```

Where `K` is the partition key, `C` is the cluster key, `V` is a value and `COUNTER` is a counter column.

Generally, the above table is queried as follows:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE K1 = A & K2 = B & C1 = X & C2 = Y & C3 = Z.
```

This results in about 500 rows being returned per query. As seen, each row is linked to a COUNTER column. Specifically, each combination of `K1, K2, C1, C2, C3` is linked to a *different* COUNTER value.

How am I suppose to model this table, if the COUNTER has to be moved to an entirely different table?

If I understand correctly, the only way to do this, is to define another table -> `table_counter` without any of the values (`V`):

```
K1 K2 C1 C2 C3 COUNTER
```

However, I have several issues with this approach:

**1)** It seems extremely inelegant to break up a logically cohesive table like this

**2)** It means that whenever I want to execute the previous query I would essentially need to execute two queries, instead of one, just to get the counter information linked to each `K1 K2 C1 C2 C3` combination

**3)** I would also be forced to combine the results of the two queries above into a single data structure on the client side (for it to be useful)

Is this correct? If yes, is there an alternative to COUNTER column where I could add the COUNTER column to the first table?

One approach I was thinking of is to use a regular `INTEGER` as the counter column. Whenever the counter column needs to be updated I can read the current counter (integer) value and increment it on the client side and then write the new value back to the database. I understand that I won’t be protected from concurrent reads/writes so that if two clients read the counter value at the same time, and they both increment/update it, one write (update) will be lost (e.g, only the last write will be preserved). However, I can live with the occasional lost write as we are not tracking anything critical where a single (or handful) of lost writes will make a major difference. I also understand that this would require a read and then a write (two operations) each time I want to update the counter column, however, it allows me to keep the counter column as part of the original table as well as reduce the querying from two tables to one. Additionally, there would be no need to combine the results of querying two tables on the client side with this design. Seems more efficient than using a counter column and much more elegant.

Is this approach a viable alternative to the COUNTER column? Are there any pitfalls I missed? Is there another approach that might work better in my example?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An Alternative to the "classic" DRDT-inspired ([but not quite](https://aphyr.com/posts/294-jepsen-cassandra#counters)) counter column is to use Scylla's [lightweight transactions](https://docs.scylladb.com/using-scylla/lwt/) (LWT) - basically your counter becomes a normal integer column, which you can read normally if you wish, but writes use a conditional update (UPDATE ... IF ...). For example to modify value V **and** also increment the counter you can:

1. Read the current value of the row
2. Decide on the new value of V and increment the counter, and finally
3. Write back the row with the new V and the incremented counter witht the condition (IF) the current counter is still the original value of the counter.
4. If step 3 failed, i.e., the IF condition wasn't true, goto step 1.

This pattern is known as "optimistic locking" - step 1-2 are "optimistic" in assuming that the new item they build will be able to be written, but if some other concurrent update beat us, step 1-2 will need to be repeated. This is to contrast with pessimistic locking approaches, where the client "takes a lock", and only after knowing it is holding the lock, bothers to calculate the new value of the item (step 2).

LWT is much more powerful than counters, and you can do with it a lot more than you can do with counters. Reads can be as efficient as regular reads, but note that writes do become slower. Scylla is working on a next-generation LWT implementation based on Raft (the current implementation is based on Paxos), so you can expect improvements in LWT write performance in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent response. Just to be clear, using LWT still requires the client to submit two transactions - one to read the current value and update the value on the client's side and a second transaction to write the new value to db. In other words, it's not possible to combine reading and updating  into a single transaction with LWT.  In other words, LWT only ensures that a concurrent write is not lost but it still requires two transactions from the client. In a case where I don't mind losing the occasional write a regular integer column without LWT would suffice. Do you concur?

Comment: Also, when would you recommend using LWT instead of custom COLUMN counter? Only when we expect few writes on the column or always? Thanks!

Comment: CQL does not currently have the **syntax** to increment a non-counter column - doing `UPDATE ... X = X + 1` will be an error if X is not a counter column. Both with LWT and without LWT. So you need to do a separate read - even though the underlying LWT implementation could have handle an atomic increment just fine without a read. Remember, though, that if the counter is not stand-alone and is used for optimistic locking (as I explained above) you would need that extra read anyway.
And yes, if you don't care about write isolation and missed increments, you can just use an unsafe read+write.